# Is it possible to interact between ASP.Net page and Silverlight?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, silverlight-4.0, integration

Say I have a Silverlight Child Windows that uses as a web browser to open access ASPX page.
The ASP page will contains a close button, when user click the close button, it should close the Silverlight Child Window.

I don't know if there is any way to do that? I wonder if I can use javascript to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can.  Silverlight can communicate with the DOM and Javascript can communicate with the DOM. So, in since they both have a communication medium they can both communicate.

Are you using the Browser control in silverlight to open the aspx page? or are you poping up a child browser window?

Either way, it should be possible. I would post some code but this has been well documented.
Here is a link to get you started.
[Communicating between Javascript and Silverlight](http://web.archive.org/web/20120404200116/http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/07/08/tip-of-the-day-15-communicating-between-javascript-amp-silverlight.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, so my asummption is correct! The link you have provide is short and easy to understand, thanks again.

Comment: link's dead, goes to general SL page